# jtable not triggering to clicks made on custom action buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-jtable

My site is code in ASP.NET MVC 3.0.

with libraries:
jQuery 3.0.0,
jQuery Validation 1.17.0,
(I'm not sure which others can be useful mentioning).

> My problem happens when testing in Internet Explorer 11, exactly when user press a button created as a "Custom Action" using [jTable.org](http://www.jtable.org). This test happens in a Windows 2012 Server.
>
> **The same site tested on Firefox in same server is working without this or any other issue.**

In IE, the regular buttons created by jTable for Create, Edit and Delete actions, are working.

This is the code for the View:

```
@model SuperSBL2.WebMVC3.ViewModels.HTEList
           
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Administrar HTEs";
}

@section CssImport{
    <style>
        div.filtering
        {
            border: 1px solid #999;
            margin-bottom: 5px;
            padding: 10px;
            background-color: #EEE;
        }
    </style>
}


<h2>Administrar HTEs</h2>


<div class="filtering">
    <form>
        <label>Línea de Producción: <input type="text" name="ProductionLineName" id="ProductionLineName" /></label>
        <label>Area: <input type="text" name="AreaName" id="AreaName" /></label>
        <label>Operación: <input type="text" name="OperationName" id="OperationName" /></label>
        <br /><label>Modelo: <input type="text" name="ModelName" id="ModelName" /></label>
        <label>Tipo (ensameble/subensamble): <input type="text" name="HTETypeName" id="HTETypeName" /></label>
        <button type="submit" id="LoadRecordsButton" class="btn btn-primary">Buscar registros</button>
    </form>
</div>


<div id="HTEContainer" style="width: 1200px; "></div>

<br />

<button type="submit" id="GoBack" class="btn btn-default">REGRESAR</button>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        //Localization texts
        var spanishMessages = {
            serverCommunicationError: 'Error de comunicación con el servidor, no puedo conectarme a la API.',
            loadingMessage: 'Obteniendo datos...',
            noDataAvailable: 'No hay datos disponibles!',
            addNewRecord: 'Nuevo HTE',
            editRecord: 'Editar HTE',
            areYouSure: 'Estás seguro?',
            deleteConfirmation: 'Estás a punto de borrar éste registro. Por favor confirma.',
            save: 'Guardar HTE',
            saving: 'Grabando',
            cancel: 'Cancelar',
            deleteText: 'Borrar HTE',
            deleting: 'Borrando',
            error: 'Error',
            close: 'Cerrar',
            cannotLoadOptionsFor: 'No puedo cargar opciones para campo {0}',
            pagingInfo: 'Mostrando {0} a {1} de {2} registros',
            pageSizeChangeLabel: 'Registros',
            gotoPageLabel: 'Ir a página',
            canNotDeletedRecords: 'No puedo borrar {0} de {1} registros!',
            deleteProggress: 'Borrado {0} de {1} registros, procesando...'
        };

        $('#HTEContainer').jtable({
            messages: spanishMessages, //Localizacion
            title: 'Lista de HTEs',
            paging: true,
            pageSize: 10,
            sorting: true,
            defaultSorting: 'AreaName ASC',
            selecting: true,
            actions: {
                listAction: '@Url.Action("HTEListForGrid")',
                deleteAction: '@Url.Action("DeleteHTE")',
                updateAction: '@Url.Action("UpdateHTE")',
                createAction: '@Url.Action("CreateHTE")'
            },
            fields: {
                HTEHeaderId: {
                    key: true,
                    create: false,
                    edit: false,
                    list: false
                },

                HTETypeID: {
                    title: 'Tipo',
                    list: true,
                    edit: false,
                    create: true,
                    options: '@Url.Action("GetHTETypeOptions","HTE")'
                },

                LineID: {
                    title: 'Línea de Producción',
                    //width: '35%',
                    list: true,
                    options: '@Url.Action("GetProductionLinesOptions","MasterData")'
                },

                AreaId: {
                    title: 'Area',
                    dependsOn: 'LineID', // jTable builds cascade dropdowns!
                    //width: '35%',
                    list: true,
                    options: function (data) {
                        if (data.source == 'list') {
                            //Return url of all countries for optimization. 
                            //This method is called for each row on the table and jTable caches options based on this url.
                            return '/MasterData/GetAreasOptionsByProductionLineID?productionLineId=0';
                        }

                        //This code runs when user opens edit/create form or changes continental combobox on an edit/create form.
                        //data.source == 'edit' || data.source == 'create'
                        return '/MasterData/GetAreasOptionsByProductionLineID?productionLineId=' + data.dependedValues.LineID;
                    }
                },

                OperationID: {
                    title: 'Operación',
                    dependsOn: 'AreaId', // jTable builds cascade dropdowns!
                    //width: '35%',
                    list: true,
                    options: function (data) {
                        if (data.source == 'list') {
                            //Return url of all countries for optimization. 
                            //This method is called for each row on the table and jTable caches options based on this url.
                            return '/MasterData/GetOperationOptionsByAreaID?areaId=0';
                        }

                        //This code runs when user opens edit/create form or changes continental combobox on an edit/create form.
                        //data.source == 'edit' || data.source == 'create'
                        return '/MasterData/GetOperationOptionsByAreaID?areaId=' + data.dependedValues.AreaId;
                    }
                },

                ModelID: {
                    title: 'Modelo',
                    dependsOn: 'LineID', // jTable builds cascade dropdowns!
                    //width: '35%',
                    list: true,
                    options: function (data) {
                        if (data.source == 'list') {
                            //Return url of all countries for optimization. 
                            //This method is called for each row on the table and jTable caches options based on this url.
                            return '/MasterData/GetModelOptionsByProductionLine?productionLineId=0';
                        }

                        //This code runs when user opens edit/create form or changes continental combobox on an edit/create form.
                        //data.source == 'edit' || data.source == 'create'
                        return '/MasterData/GetModelOptionsByProductionLine?productionLineId=' + data.dependedValues.LineID;
                    }
                },


                OperationAvailableTime: {
                    title: 'Tiempo disponible',
                    //width: '35%',
                    list: true,
                    edit: false,
                    create: false
                } ,

                Effiency: {
                    title: 'Effciencia',
                    //width: '35%',
                    list: true
                } ,

                RevisionNumber: {
                    title: '# Revisión',
                    //width: '35%',
                    list: true,
                    edit: false,
                    create: false,
                    defaultValue: '0'
                },

                RevisionDate: {
                    title: 'Fecha Revisión',
                    //width: '15%',
                    type: 'date',
                    list: true,
                    edit: false,
                    create: false,
                    displayFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
                },

                ProductionRate: {
                    title: 'Producción Diaria',
                    //width: '35%',
                    list: true
                },

                Taktime: {
                    title: 'Taktime',
                    //width: '35%',
                    list: true
                },

                RequiredHeadCount: {
                    title: 'Head Count',
                    //width: '35%',
                    list: true
                },


                HTEStatus: {
                    title: 'Status',
                    //width: '35%',
                    list: true,
                    edit: false,
                    create: false,
                    options: '@Url.Action("GetHTEStatusOptions","HTE")'
                },

                Active: {
                    title: 'Activo?',
                    //width: '12%',
                    type: 'checkbox',
                    list: true,
                    edit: false,
                    create: false,
                    values: { 'false': 'No Activo', 'true': 'Activo' },
                    defaultValue: 'true'
                },
                
                Overspeed: {
                    title: 'OverSpeed',
                    create: true,
                    edit: true,
                    list: true
                    //, defaultValue: @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.OverSpeed))
                },

                CustomActionAdmin: {
                    title: '',
                    //width: '1%',
                    sorting: false,
                    create: false,
                    edit: false,
                    list: true,
                    display: function (data) {
                        if (data.record) {
                            return '<button title="" id="btnAdmin"  class="jtable-command-button glyphicon glyphicon-cog" onclick="transferAdmin(' + data.record.HTEHeaderId + '); return false;"></button>';
                        }
                    }
                },
                
                CustomActionActivities: {
                    title: '',
                    //width: '1%',
                    sorting: false,
                    create: false,
                    edit: false,
                    list: true,
                    display: function (data) {
                        if (data.record) {
                            return '<button title="" id="btnAdmin"  class="jtable-command-button glyphicon glyphicon-wrench" onclick="transferHTEDetails(' + data.record.HTEHeaderId + '); return false;"></button>';
                        }
                    }
                }               
            }
        });

        //Re-load records when user click 'load records' button.
        $('#LoadRecordsButton').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#HTEContainer').jtable('load', {
                ProductionLineName: $('#ProductionLineName').val(),
                AreaName: $('#AreaName').val(),
                OperationName: $('#OperationName').val(),
                ModelName: $('#ModelName').val(),
                HTETypeName: $('#HTETypeName').val()
            });
        });

        //Load all records when page is first shown
        $('#LoadRecordsButton').click();


        $('#GoBack').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            window.location.replace("/HTE");
        });

    });

    function transferAdmin(hteHeaderId) {
        window.location.replace("/HTE/AdminSettings/" + hteHeaderId);
    };

    function transferHTEDetails(hteHeaderId) {
        window.location.replace("/HTE/HTEActivitiesList/?HTEHeaderId=" + hteHeaderId);
    };

</script>
<br />


@section scripts {

}
```

---

Now, this is the code for the _Layout.cshtml in use:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
@{
    var jTableStyle = "metro/blue/jtable.css";
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request["jTableStyle"]))
    {
        jTableStyle = Request["jTableStyle"];
    }
}
<html lang="es-mx">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Super Sistema Balanceo de Líneas - @ViewBag.Title - </title>

    
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/metroblue/jquery-ui.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    @*<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/highlight.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />*@
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jtable/themes/" + jTableStyle)" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/syntaxhighligher/styles/shCore.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/syntaxhighligher/styles/shThemeDefault.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/bootstrap.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    

    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/core.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/datepicker.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/theme.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/bootstrap-theme.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />



    @RenderSection("CssImport", false)



    
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-3.0.0.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-migrate-3.0.0.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui.unobtrusive-3.0.0.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.date.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    
@*    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate-vsdoc.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>*@

    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/modernizr-2.8.3.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>


    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/syntaxhighligher/shCore.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/syntaxhighligher/shBrushJScript.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/syntaxhighligher/shBrushXml.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/syntaxhighligher/shBrushCSharp.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/syntaxhighligher/shBrushSql.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/moment.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/respond.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jtable/jquery.jtable.js")"></script>

    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jtablesite.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>



</head>
<body>
    @Html.Partial("_NavBar")
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - Super Sistema Balanceo de Líneas</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
    @RenderSection("CustomScripts", required: false)
</body>



</html>
```

---

This is a picture of system in Internet Explorer, displayed as expected:
[page displayed in Internet Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KfHNb.png)

You can see the rendering is as expected, not issue on this area with Internet Explorer.

- Red arrows indicates the buttons created as Custom Action, once pressed up, nothings happens. When the IE developer tools are displayed, I press the buttons indicated with Read arrows, nothing happens: not even an error in console, not even an error in Network tab, nothing at all. This is error I'm having.
- Green arrows indicates the buttons created by jTable for EDIT, CREATE and DELETE actions as part of the grid. These buttons are working perfect. No issue on this area. See these pictures:

  - [Page in IE showing modal for New record](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHOFT.png)
  - [Page in IE showing modal for Edit record](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8h22H.png)

I hopes you guys can provide any idea.

Thanks,
Gerardo.

Comment: Please provide your code sample or jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

This a complex senario, so I cannot replicate it.

I observe from your code, that you are adding click handlers via javascript in the `button` definitions. Have you tried applying the click handler via jQuery

```
display: function (data) {
    var $but = '';
    if (data.record) {
        $but = $('<button title=""  class="jtable-command-button glyphicon glyphicon-cog" ></button>');
        $but.click(transferAdmin(data.record.HTEHeaderId));
    }
    return $but;
}
```

I would also point out your original code was creating a button using the same id `btnAdmin` on every row of the table which is neither good practice or useful, so I have omitted that, as it is possibly another reason why IE gets confused.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @misterP for his reply. After having bad times with this, I managed to understand what was wrong, and fixed it.

Let me try to explain fixes to issue I was having.

#### 1) Main problem was that in IE, my jQuery logic was not working, when it worked in Firefox and Chrome. I was not aware of IE compatilibity modes that are fixed with the meta tag at  level. So, on file _layout.chtml, I set the following:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    ...
```

#### 2) Regarding how I managed the functionality on the custom action, I read online that when working with jQuery targeting dynamic elements, we should start the filtering against a fixed tag --- hence I used `ContainerForJTable`. I declare a custom attribute `seleccionable` on the dynamic object:

```
    display: function (data) {
        if (data.record) {
            return '<button id="' + data.record.FileID + '"  class="jtable-command-button glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open seleccionable"></button>';
        }
    }
```

#### 3) I wrote a function (outside of the jtable object creation --- `$('#ContainerForJTable').jtable({..`) to add an event to objects matching a filter using my custom attribute:

```
    $('#ContainerForJTable').on('click', '.seleccionable', function () {
        var theID = $(this).attr("id");
        //console.log("The id is " + theID);
        viewFiles(theID);
    });
```

After these changes, the jtables objects had been working without any issues.

thanks,